# Duplicate class com.google.common found in modules guava error

Tags: android, android-studio

These are errors which I am facing in my project because of this I am not able to run my project

> Duplicate class com.google.common.annotations.Beta found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.annotations.GwtIncompatible found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.annotations.VisibleForTesting found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.base.Absent found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.base.AbstractIterator found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.base.AbstractIterator$1 found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.base.AbstractIterator$State found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.base.Ascii found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$1 found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$2 found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$3 found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$4 found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$5 found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$StringConverter found in
> modules jetified-guava-27.1-android
> (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0
> (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate class
> com.google.common.base.CharMatcher found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$1 found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$And found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$BitSetMatcher found in
> modules jetified-guava-27.1-android
> (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0
> (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate class
> com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$FastMatcher found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$NegatedFastMatcher found in
> modules jetified-guava-27.1-android
> (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0
> (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate class
> com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or found in modules
> jetified-guava-27.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and
> jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0) Duplicate
> class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$RangesMatcher found in
> modules jetified-guava-27.1-android
> (com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0
> (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)

Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try `exclude` on your implementation.

```kotlin
implementation(...) {
    exclude(group = "com.google.guava", module = "guava-jdk5")
}
```

Comment: Do I need to write this in my all implementations or at any specific implementation as I have many implementations in gradle file

Comment: Please help me out in finding which implementation can cause this, If there is specific implementation which can cause this